# Beginner question about persisting data in ASP.NET Core and Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

the task is uploading new employees to a database, which works. However, when I need to restart the app I run
`sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=mypassword' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux`
and then
`dotnet ef database update`
which leaves me with only my initial seeding data. How would I get data persistence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solution to it. I will not provide you complete solution but would be more or like suggestion.

1. First time when you create container with the help of command you mention.

   ```
   sudo docker run --name sql1 -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=mypassword' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
   ```

Give it some name like I have provided --name sql1.

So when you stop then stop that container.

```
  docker stop sql1
```

nexttime when you need

```
  docker start sql1
```

2. Next solution is volume. You have to create volume in your host or some shared directory and it needs to share with docker so it will store data over there and it will present even if you destroy container and create it again then it will get attach.

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash